# What's the replacement for history's useBeforeUnload to show a confirmation dialog in react-router?

Tags: react-router, history.js

In the [example here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md#examples) and in this [issue comment](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/3147#issuecomment-200565770) it is suggested to use the useBeforeUnload function of [history](https://github.com/mjackson/history).

However, this function is gone. It seems to be [removed without replacement in the current 4.x version](https://github.com/mjackson/history/blob/master/CHANGES.md#v400-0):

> Removed the "middleware" API (i.e. all "use" functions).

What's a good way to handle catch these "before unload" cases now in order to show a confirmation dialog?

Comment: The function is back in React Router 6.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at the code for [history](https://github.com/mjackson/history)'s createBrowserHistory, it looks like the `block` function does what you need. From the docs:

```
// Register a simple prompt message that will be shown the
// user before they navigate away from the current page.
const unblock = history.block('Are you sure you want to leave this page?')

// Or use a function that returns the message when it's needed.
history.block((location, action) => {
  // The location and action arguments indicate the location
  // we're transitioning to and how we're getting there.

  // A common use case is to prevent the user from leaving the
  // page if there's a form they haven't submitted yet.
  if (input.value !== '')
    return 'Are you sure you want to leave this page?'
})

// To stop blocking transitions, call the function returned from block().
unblock()
```

https://github.com/mjackson/history#blocking-transitions